# can't push my project to the right location in the git repository

Tags: git

I've wrote a java class and I can't push it to the right place in my git repo.

Now I have 2 versions of the code in the git repo - one is the code skeleton that we got (without implementation), and the second is the right and full version but not in the right path.

I need to move it from:

```
ap2023-hw5/AP-hw5/ap2023-hw5/src/main/java/smarticulous/Smarticulous.java
```

to:

```
ap2023-hw5/src/main/java/smarticulous/Smarticulous.java
```

I've  tried to `git push` from several paths but no one pushed it to the right one.

Comment: You have to move the file in your repository first, and then push. See the linked question for how to move a file in your repository.

Comment: `git push` does not move files around. `git mv` does. After you have done so, you have to `git commit`. And *then* you can push.